# Read model per bounded context

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

i have a question related to read models in cqrs.

Assume we have two bounded contexts: **A** and **B**

In context **A** we build a readmodel based on the events from context **A**. We have some kind of dao to access the readmodel in A.

Now assume that **B** needs the same read model as **A**. 
As far as i understood, bounded context shouldn't depend on each other.

So how can i use the model from A. I see three possiblities to solve this

1. Create an API Module for the read model in A and use this in context B
   (Would be a dependency between A and B)
2. Create an seperate read model in context B thats exactly the same as in A 
   (Would result in code duplication)
3. Create a service facade (REST or SOAP or whatever) in B that is accessible from A to provide the read model
   (possibly the service doesnt provide exactly the data needed)

Comment: It looks like Share kernal if A and B  both need this read model.

Comment: Hm... Two good answers with equal upvotes and neither accepted. Have you come to any conclusion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your read models **don't belong** to any bounded contexts, they are **produced** by some domain objects in some bounded context. But they are a separate component of your system.

Your bounded context **shouldn't need** any read model. Read model is an **output** of the domain, not the input. If you need 2 BC communicate, use events, not read models. Read models are for GUI/reporting, not for processing business rules.

Comment: I generally agree with this, but what if you need to validate a domain object based on data aggregated from other areas of your BC? Unique Email Address for example. You are going to need to read data from somewhere, so the approach I have seen used is to have a service interface to some read model. It's not ideal, but software is all about compromise after all :)

Comment: The example you gave suggests ther is some another aggregate that is not yet discovered by the business analyst. For instance all the Customers with their emails belong to Tennant aggregate that can enforce the uniqueness invariant?

Answer (score 9):

It's actually very common to have dependencies between contexts, see relationships and context mapping in the [DDD Reference](http://domainlanguage.com/ddd/patterns/DDD_Reference_2011-01-31.pdf).

In your example, context B depends on context A. Depending on the type of relationship (upstream-downstream, partnership, ...) context A decides how to let context B integrate with them (open-host, customer/supplier, ...).

Context A can provide a read model, events, or both. Integrating via events gives you independence, though integrating via a read model might be more practical for your example (but might cause friction once context A decides to diverge). Factors to take into account are  your relationship with the other context, and the probability of change vs. cost of change.